# It is possible to build to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I noticed there is no `ts` option for `"target"` mentioned in the documentation. I would like to build my project into one big .ts file so that I can paste it in CodePen. What are my options for automation?

Comment: What documentation? "target"? Please provide more information as you have given very little to go on.

Comment: @TimBJames I meant the property `target` for the `tsconfig.json` config file, documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: You can use the `--out` option to combine the resulting `js` but if you just want to concat `ts` files a powershell/cmd/bash script might be simpler solution. The compiler has no option to output the same typescript.